# How to remove scrollbar in order to make the website fit in the browser

Tags: jquery, html, browser

I made a website from my laptop. While testing my website in my laptop there was no any scroll bars neither horizontal nor vertical was appearing in any of the browser.

But if now if i test my website, in some other computer , it is showing horizontal and vertical scroll bar.

To avoid this i used css property `body{zoom: 70%;}` . But this code is working in few browser and also in only few pages.

Can anyone please suggest me a solution for my problem.

Comment: just tell me what you want your page to do when is shown in different browsers? (I mean the small window).

Comment: @imsiso I want to fit my content in all browser without any scroll bar. Because the content of my website is very small. i think there is no need of scrollbar

Comment: For someone who is in the web development field, your website is poorly designed.

Comment: ok so what do you want to do with that do you want to hide extra width(for sure not) or you want to shrink it to fit?

Comment: @asprin  I designed, please give me suggestion to improve my website designed. Please tell.

Comment: @imsiso I think `shrink to fit` will be better solution. What you say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok maybe this helps you.

```
#main {
width: 90%;
margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Is this will fit in all  system browser with respect to the web degin standard design.?

Comment: it will work but I dont know what 'web degin standard design' means.and please just don't forget about supporting with voting up my answer and useful comments.(-:

Comment: Do not worry about support. I will do at the end of the day.  I mean   So can you suggest me how to improve my website shown above. I know my website designing is not go0d–

Comment: about voting up I just wanted to mention it. and about your question what do you want we to say? with study and spending time. As I'm doing for my website.with searching and asking specific clear questions in places like here. do you want me to tell you the thing you will get maybe in 6 months?

Comment: Sorry! I am not understanding your comment clearly.  I asked you  give me few tips so that i can improve my website deigning..

Comment: no I said that because you just had removed it from your question.and its not a thing I can explain here.we should go on chat.so let me know when your reputation became 20.(you can do it with answering a question or even accepting an answer to your question with tick mark).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28080/discussion-between-imsiso-and-user2180861)

Comment: your welcome.(-:. but just remember one of most important things in forums supporting. with answers and with voting up or down answers(with up or down arrows).in everywhere.(-:

Answer (score 0):

You can always use `overflow: hidden;` I beleive.

Comment: I think this is not fine. Because if i use this, then users can not see few hidden part of my website. They can not see because they can not scroll

Comment: Oh I thought you actually wanted to delete the scroll bars my bad.

Answer (score 0):

```
#main {
width: 1399px;
margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
}
```

The `width` on `#main` is the issue, remove that to get rid of horizontal scrollbar or use `width: 100%;`. Don't worry about vertical scrollbars, if content is longer than view port, then they **will** appear.

Also I see your markup has tables for content, dont use tables for anything except tabular data. Good Luck!

Comment: `width` is necessary to keep the main content centered. Otherwise `margin` auto won't work

Comment: I know my website design is bad. So can you suggest me how to improve my website  shown above.

Answer (score 0):

You probably won't be able to avoid vertical scrollbars on all browsers. Generally, content is made to flow downward on the web intentionally. To avoid the horizontal scrollbars, you need to avoid elements on your page with static widths. If you specify all of the elements on your page as a percentage width then the page will scale to the width of the browser appropriately. You do need to set a minimum width in most cases. Basically, you need to learn about the different layout types. Here's a resource on the topic: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/06/02/fixed-vs-fluid-vs-elastic-layout-whats-the-right-one-for-you/